# dotcloud push fail (rsync error: unexplained error (code 255))

Tags: ssh, dotcloud

I have a problem with the "dotcloud push" command. I have followed the [quick start guide](http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/firststeps/quickstart/) but at the end, the command `dotcloud push helloworldapp` gives me the following error:

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
>   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
>   Warning: The SSH connection failed
>   Please try again. If the problem persists, send an email to support@dotcloud.com.
>   Also please check that your are allowed to make an SSH connection to a custom port.
>   Abort.

I've tried to connect with ssh to dotcloud@uploader.dotcloud.com:443, and I get:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname uploader.dotcloud.com:443: Name or service not known

How can I solve this?

Comment: Same thing here on OS X 10.6.

Comment: Same thing here on OS X 10.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was most likely a temporary issue with the dotCloud API. Once the issue was fixed, your push should have been able to complete. If not, please contact dotCloud support for more help.

See http://help.dotcloud.com for a full list of ways to get help for dotCloud.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will have corrected the issue for everybody, but I ran into the very same problem. I asked for help on the #dotcloud IRC channel, and the issue was solved 15 minutes later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I was missing the **dotcloud.yml** file in my app's root directory. After I added it the **dotcloud push** command worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got this error about *connection unexpectedly closed* more often, try increasing the server alive interval value in your SSH config (`~/.ssh/config`), e.g.

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 6
```

See: [What the options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3026/21471)